# How to Mock EntityManager in a serviceTest with Symfony?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, symfony

Sorry my question is very long.

**How to mock entityManager in a service test extending KernelTestCase ?**

Now, the explanation and my tests...

I am using Symfony3.2. My Application is standard. I have some Controller and I use WebTestCase to test them.

Generaly, my Controller verify parameters, call a service/a manager, handle some variables and push them to view and my test are pretty simple in test extending **WebTestCase**.

```
/**
 * Test New Game Action
 */
public function testFooAction(){
    //We mock the Service
    $fooService = $this
        ->getMockBuilder(GameService::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $fooService->expects(self::once())
        ->method('barMethod')
        ->willReturn($result);

    //We create the client
    $client = static::createClient();
    $container = $client->getContainer();

    //I put my mock here
    $container->set('app.game-service', $fooService);

    //I launch the request
    $client->request('GET', '/foo');
    //I handle the response
    $response = $client->getResponse();

    //I do some tests like this one
    self::assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());

}
```

As you can see, **I do not call EntityManger**, because I use **Services** and these lines to put my Services's Mock

```
    //We create the client
    $client = static::createClient();
    $container = $client->getContainer();

    //I put my mock here
    $container->set('app.game-service', $fooService);
```

I have a problem to mock Entity Manager in my services. My Controller is tested but not My Service.

Here is the constructor initialized a simple **protected** property entityManager. The problem is this *protected* as you will see further...

```
   /**
     * FooService constructor.
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
           $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }
```

To Test my Service, here is my initial code :

```
<?php
class FooServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
     * Foo Service.
     *
     * @var FooService
     */
    private $fooService;

    /**
     * Prepares the environment before running each test.
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        self::bootKernel();
        $this->fooService = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('app.foo-service') //HERE IS HOW I HANDLE MY SERVICE TO TEST IT
        ;

    }
```

testStart Works perfectly, there is some database interaction.

I know that I can rollback data during test. But I want to Mock entityManager **to verify the call of** `commit` **method**.

I try this to mock entity manager in my setUp :

```
    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $entityManager = $this
            ->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $entityManager
            ->expects(once())  // I WANT EXACTLY ONE CALL TO COMMIT METHOD
            ->method('commit')  
            ->willReturn(null);

        self::bootKernel();
        $container = static::$kernel->getContainer();
        $container->set('doctrine.orm.entity_manager', $entityManager); // THIS LINE DOES NOTHING <=======
        $this->gameService = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('app.game-service')
        ;
```

Thes code doesn't work. Mock is not in place. I still have the true entityManager. I think it is because the container is already closed. Do it is nut usefull to set

Like a Barbarian, I change the entityManager property to **public**

And I do that :

```
    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $entityManagerMock = $this
            ->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $entityManagerMock
            ->expects(once())  // I WANT EXACTLY ONE CALL TO commit METHOD
            ->method('commit')  
            ->willReturn(null);

        self::bootKernel();
        $this->gameService = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('app.game-service')
        ;
        $this->gameService->entityManager = entityManagerMock;
```

It works perfectly. Test can be run. But it is NOT a good practice to have an entityManager in a public property

My question is : How to mock entityManager in a service test ?

(Sorry, I am not fluent in english)

Comment: I think you should choose your test to be either a unit test (where you will mock your dependencies, or a WebTestCase, in which case you should use a test database and use your app as normal without mocking. I also loved "Like a Barbarian, I change the entityManager property to public"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all in your code

```
$container->set('doctrine.orm.entity_manager'); // THIS LINE DOES NOTHING <=======
```

I'm sure you missed second parameter :)

Another note: **don't mock what you don't own**. 
In future you will run `composer update` and EntityManager's `commit` will have some optional `isReallyCommit` parameter. Your code will be broken, but you will not notice it, because tests are green. I understand that it very unlikely, but anyway it's just example. I think the good practice here is to

- Have some adapter with entity manager incapsulated
- Mock that adapter in service unit tests
- Test your adapter with functional tests against real database without mocking anything

Or just don't **unit** test your service but make **functional** tests with real database interactions

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I'm not sure to understand what you mean with this sentence : Have some adapter with entity manager incapsulated. Can you edit your answer to give me a short example, please ?